# Ninject web api - System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I got this error when using Ninject with Web API.

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        try
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog(ex.Message +"-------------------------------"+ ex.Source +"---" +ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel1()
    {
        WriteLog("CreateKernel1 -- 5");
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            WriteLog("CreateKernel1 -- 6");
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            NinjectServiceRegister ser = new NinjectServiceRegister(kernel);
            ser.RegisterServices();
            AutoMapperConfig autoMapperConfig = new AutoMapperConfig(kernel);
            autoMapperConfig.RegisterServices();
            WriteLog("CreateKernel1 -- 7");
            kernel.BindHttpFilter<ApiAuthneticatonFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Global).WhenControllerHas<CollectorsAuthenticationAttribute>();
            kernel.BindHttpFilter<CollectorsAuthorizationFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Global).WhenControllerHas<CollectorsAuthroizationAttribute>();
            WriteLog("CreateKernel1 -- 8");
            System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Authenticate -- 9" + ex.Message);
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**error message:**

> -CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI---System.TypeLoadException: Method 'ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync' in type
>   'CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI.InfraStructure.Authorization.CollectorsAuthorizationFilter'
>   from assembly 'CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
>   at
>   CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel1() 
>   at Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1
>   createKernelCallback)    at
>   CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in
>   D:\IGATE\InvogateWeb-Siva\InvogateWeb\CollectorsApp.MobileWebAPI\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:line
>   34

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution?

Comment: No friend. I didn't. I am still trying. same error Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback)

Comment: This error emerge after I updated some packages. (not Ninject!) So I've manage to overcome it by downgrading packages back. But I didn't have time to figure out which package upgrade led to this issue :(

Comment: Dll issue resolved. thanks for your kind support. it is working fine.